# Quadratic fit function of two large data samples in python to predict

Tags: python, function, machine-learning, prediction, quadratic

using this csv:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QbFIUE1AcFCOgDZH5K2vPColxXeBVDV-sJhS9On2BYY/edit?usp=sharing

I'm trying to figure out how to write a program to fit a quadratic function to predict the change in global temperature
(y) as a function of Year (x).
The function in question is:

[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc6cy.png)

The program should create a plot showing the training examples and the quadratic fit
to the data.

This is what I have so far as a trial to figure out the basics. Just need to convert it:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Generate 200 training examples

m = 200
x = np.random.randn(m)
y = np.random.randn(1) * x ** 2 + np.random.randn(1) * x + 
np.random.randn(1)
y = y + 0.4 * np.random.randn(m)

#Quadratic Fit

X = np.transpose([np.ones(m), x, x ** 2])
print(np.shape(X))
print(np.shape(y))

theta = inv(np.transpose(X) @X) @ np.transpose(X) @ y

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')

xp = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
yp = theta[0] + theta[1] * xp + theta[2] * xp ** 2

plt.plot(xp, yp, 'r-')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the program you were looking for, using batch gradient descent. Note that i did not focus on making the code optimal, but readable and easy to understand:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Generate 200 training examples

m = 200
x = np.random.randn(m)
y = np.random.randn(1) * x ** 2 + np.random.randn(1) * x + np.random.randn(1)
y = y + 0.4 * np.random.randn(m)

theta = np.random.randn(3,1) # Start with random theta values

# Train the model for a couple of iterations and chose a learning rate
epochs = 60  # Train for 600 epochs if you wish to get almost identical result to normal ecuations result
learning_rate = 0.1
len_x = len(x)

for epoch in range(epochs):
    # Calculate the gradients of the LSE cost function with respect to each theta parameter

    theta_gradients = np.zeros((3,1)) # Reinitialize the gradients

    theta_gradients[2] = sum((label - theta[2] * value ** 2 - theta[1] * value - theta[0]) * (-value**2)
                             for value,label in zip(x,y))/len_x
    theta_gradients[1] = sum((label - theta[2] * value ** 2 - theta[1] * value - theta[0]) * (-value) 
                             for value,label in zip(x,y))/len_x
    theta_gradients[0] = sum((label - theta[2] * value ** 2 - theta[1] * value - theta[0]) * (-1) 
                             for value,label in zip(x,y))/len_x
    # The zip funtion creates an iterable object by merging x and y.
    # Basically we are iterating through the whole data set for each computation.

    # Update the theta parameters using descent

    for i in range(3):
        theta[i] = theta[i] - learning_rate * theta_gradients[i]


# At the end of the training you can plot the function with the new learned parameters


print("Learned thetas:", theta)

xp = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
yp = theta[0] + theta[1] * xp + theta[2] * xp ** 2

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')
plt.plot(xp, yp, 'r-')
plt.title("Learned function")

#Quadratic Fit (for comparison)

X = np.transpose([np.ones(m), x, x ** 2])
# print(np.shape(X))
# print(np.shape(y))

theta = inv(np.transpose(X) @X) @ np.transpose(X) @ y
print("Normal thetas:", theta)

yp = theta[0] + theta[1] * xp + theta[2] * xp ** 2

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')
plt.plot(xp, yp, 'r-')
plt.title("Your function (normal ecuations result)")
```

The program works in the following way : We initialize the theta parameters randomly, then we train the model for a number of epochs. On each epochs, we compute the gradients of the cost function taking into account all the data (not the most efficient method, but it should be simpler to understand) with respect to each parameter theta. Then we update each theta using the gradient descent rule. Then we plot the predicted function.

I also kept the best theoretical solution, that you calculated using the so called "normal equations", for comparisson.

The learning rate and number of epochs that i provided are good enough to fit every data set you generate, but you can play with them for experimentation, in case you want better performance at the cost of slower convergence (longer training time).
I also prinded the thetas that the model has learned, and the best theoretical thetas that can be achived, for comparrison.

If you have any questions I will be happy to answer them. If you are interested into where these concepts such as gradients or cost function come from, I suggest reading some literature about logistic regression.